# Finding the longest and-chain in spaCy

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, nlp, spacy

How can I match the longest 'and chain' available in some text?

For example, consider

"The forum had jam and berry and wine along with bread and butter and cheese and milk, even chocolate and pista!"

How can I match

```
'jam and berry and wine'
```

and

```
'bread and butter and cheese and milk'
```

without knowing the number of 'and'-separated terms?

---

This is what I tried.

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

pattern = [{'IS_ASCII': True}, {'LOWER': 'and'}, {'IS_ASCII': True}]
matcher.add("AND_PAT", None, pattern)

doc = nlp("The forum had jam and berry and wine along with bread and butter and cheese and milk, even chocolate and pista!")

for match_id, start, end in matcher(doc):
    print(doc[start: end].text)
```

but this is not doing the 'lazy' kind of matching that I need.

---

I had a look at the [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#quantifiers) and it mentions the `OP` key for making rules but that seems to be useful only when the same token is repeated consecutively.

Also, the matches should be sort of greedy and shouldn't give result as soon as an acceptable pattern is found. In the above example, the desired result is **not** like (as in my program)

```
jam and berry
berry and wine
```

but as

```
jam and berry and wine
```

This is a problem which can probably be solved with regex but I was hoping for a solution using spaCy's rule matching. Preferably without even using the `REGEX` operator as mentioned [here](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#regex).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = [{t.nbor(-1).i, t.i, t.nbor().i} for t in doc if t.text == 'and']
bag = set().union(*l) #The * operator unpacks an argument list
st = " ".join([t.text if t.i in bag else '\n' for t in doc])
result = [part.strip() for part in st.split('\n') if part.strip()]


# result = ['jam and berry and wine',
# 'bread and butter and cheese and milk',
# 'chocolate and pista']
```

Note this assumes that the first and last tokens are not 'and' tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still, I was hoping there would be a less complex and more of a straight-forward way.... Oh, well..